# webpack css build problems

Tags: css, webpack

have a small chat project. build using webpack.
All good. after build i have small main css file and second with i think css from other libraries.

Have second webpack config. to build main component of project as library to integrate to other project.

But after build i have only main css file. css file contain only my css selectors. Css from other libraries not compiled.

Why? My head is broken )))

Thanks

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const resolve = require("resolve");
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require("pnp-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require("case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin");
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const safePostCssParser = require("postcss-safe-parser");
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin");
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin");
const ModuleScopePlugin = require("react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin");
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require("react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent");
const paths = require("./paths");
const getClientEnvironment = require("./env");
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin");
const typescriptFormatter = require("react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter");
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');

// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== "false";
// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== "false";

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/; // это как вариант css в node_modules?
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassRegexMy = /\.scss$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
//   webpackEnv= "production";
  const isEnvDevelopment = false;//webpackEnv === "development";
   // поставим тут принудительно production  
  const  isEnvProduction = true === true;//webpackEnv === "production";
   console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');

   console.log(webpackEnv);
   console.log(typeof webpackEnv);
   
   
   //var outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib');
   
  // isEnvProduction = true;

  // Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
  // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
  // In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
  const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && "/";
  // Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
  // For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.

  const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === "./";

  // `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  const publicUrl = isEnvProduction
    ? publicPath.slice(0, -1)
    : isEnvDevelopment && "";
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);
  
  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
//////////    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve("style-loader"),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: Object.assign(
          {},
          shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: "../../" } : undefined
        )
      },
//////////    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
      {
        loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
        options: cssOptions
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: "postcss",
          plugins: () => [
            require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
            require("postcss-preset-env")({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: "no-2009"
              },
              stage: 3
            })
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
        }
      }
    ].filter(Boolean);
    console.log('loaders');
    console.log(loaders);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
        options: {
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
        }
      });
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    //mode: isEnvProduction ? "production" : isEnvDevelopment && "development",
    mode:  "production" ,
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? "source-map"
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && "cheap-module-source-map",
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: ['./src/chat/chatWrapper.js'],
  output: {
    path: appRoot.path+'/build/lib', //path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),  //
    filename: 'chat-library.bundle.js',  // 
    library: 'ChatLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  },

    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              // we want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
              // to apply any minfication steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
              // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
              // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
              ecma: 8
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2376
              // Pending further investigation:
              // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
              comparisons: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Terser breaking valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250
              // Pending futher investigation:
              // https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120
              inline: 2
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true
            },
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true
            }
          },
          // Use multi-process parallel running to improve the build speed
          // Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1
          parallel: true,
          // Enable file caching
          cache: true,
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  // `inline: false` forces the sourcemap to be output into a
                  // separate file
                  inline: false,
                  // `annotation: true` appends the sourceMappingURL to the end of
                  // the css file, helping the browser find the sourcemap
                  annotation: true
                }
              : false
          }
        })
      ],
      // Automatically split vendor and commons
      // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969633336732905474
      // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        name: false
      },
      // Keep the runtime chunk separated to enable long term caching
      // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
      runtimeChunk: true
    },
    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ["node_modules", "src"].concat(
        // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
        process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
      ),
      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes("ts")),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        "react-native": "react-native-web",
        styles: path.join(paths.appSrc, "styles"),
        chatSource: path.join(paths.appSrc, "chat"),
        chatStylesSource: path.join(paths.appSrc, "chat"), // вроде как работает через тильду scss. хотя в итоге тильда лишняя
        react: 'dummyReact.js'
      },
      plugins: [
        // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
        // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson])
      ],
    },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
  },
      
    
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module)
      ]
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
//              {
//              может это и не надо - там ниже для этого есть правило             
//                      test: /\.js$/,
//                      use: 'babel-loader',
//                    },
                      {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        use: [
                          'style-loader',
                          'css-loader',
                        ],
                      },      
      
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
          enforce: "pre",
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                formatter: require.resolve("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter"),
                eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint")
              },
              loader: require.resolve("eslint-loader")
            }
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc
        },
/*      {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                includePaths: ["src"]
            }
        }]
    }   ,*/

    
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve("url-loader"),
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
                // вот это вот не линкует медиа в каталог. ниже
                name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
              }
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  "babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides"
                ),

                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve("babel-plugin-named-asset-import"),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent: "@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+ref![path]"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,
                compact: isEnvProduction
              }
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/dependencies"),
                    { helpers: true }
                  ]
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,

                // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
                // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
                // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
                // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
                sourceMaps: false
              }
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
              })
            },
            
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                "sass-loader"
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true
            },
            
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
                },
                "sass-loader"
              )
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
              }
            }
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true
                }
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
      // a network request.
//      isEnvProduction &&
 //       shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
  //      new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]),
      // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
      // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
      // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
      // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
      // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
      // In development, this will be an empty string.
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
      // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
      // the requesting resource.
      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
      // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
      // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV is set to production
      // during a production build.
      // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
      // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
      // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
      // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
      // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
        //тут чтоб безусловно генерировало css 
      isEnvProduction &&   
      //  true &&
      
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
          chunkFilename: "static/css/[id].[contenthash:8].chunk.css"
        }),
      // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
      // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
      // having to parse `index.html`.
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
        publicPath: publicPath
      }),
      // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
      // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
      // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
      // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
      // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
      // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
      isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: "cdn",
          navigateFallback: publicUrl + "/index.html",
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
            // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
            new RegExp("^/_"),
            // Exclude URLs containing a dot, as they're likely a resource in
            // public/ and not a SPA route
            new RegExp("/[^/]+\\.[^/]+$")
          ]
        }),
      // TypeScript type checking
      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          typescript: resolve.sync("typescript", {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules
          }),
          async: isEnvDevelopment,
          useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
          checkSyntacticErrors: true,
          tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
          reportFiles: [
            "**",
            "!**/*.json",
            "!**/__tests__/**",
            "!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*",
            "!**/src/setupProxy.*",
            "!**/src/setupTests.*"
          ],
          watch: paths.appSrc,
          silent: true,
          // The formatter is invoked directly in WebpackDevServerUtils during development
          formatter: isEnvProduction ? typescriptFormatter : undefined
        })
    ].filter(Boolean),
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    node: {
      module: "empty",
      dgram: "empty",
      dns: "mock",
      fs: "empty",
      net: "empty",
      tls: "empty",
      child_process: "empty"
    },
    // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
    // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
    performance: false
  };
};
```

Comment: if Entry config point to index file of project - all good with css. But library ot containg root component ChatWrapper - contain whole project

Comment: I don't think anyone will be willing to help with a webpack configuration file that comprises several hundred lines of code.

Comment: found. Not a webpack problem. scss import in index.js. But component in lower level file